# PHP - Modifying Record from table in Oracle Database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am new to PHP so sorry for the lack of correct terminology. I currently have a php file that shows my database table in the browser and gives an option to edit a record. However I don't know how to connect the edit button to the specific record and bring it to the second php page to edit.

Basically how do I get the record I click to edit go through to my second PHP file!

the link to the code that is similar to how I would like my php pages to function is http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-oracle/php-oracle-oci8-edit-update-data/

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far for my first PHP script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>  
<head>  
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<?php  
$dbuser = "scott";
        $dbpassword = "tiger";
        $db = "orabis";

    $conn = oci_connect($dbuser,$dbpassword,$db);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM ATTENDEES";  
$objParse = oci_parse ($conn, $sql);  
oci_execute ($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT);  
print '<table border="1">';


            print '<tr>'; 
            print '<th>FirstName</th>'; 
            print '<th > LastName  </th>';
            print '<th > Email  </th>';
            print '<th > Address  </th>';
            print '<th > Company  </th>';
            print '<th > Title  </th> ' ;
            print '<th > City </th> ' ;
            print '<th > State  </th> ';
            print '<th > Zip  </th> ';
            print '<th> Country  </th>';
            print '<th> Phone  </th> ';
            print '<th> Edit  </th>';
            print '</tr>';  
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) {

   foreach ($row as $item) {
       print '<td>'.($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : '&nbsp').'</td>';
   }
   print '<td><a href="modify_attendee2.php">Edit</a></td>';
   print '</tr>';
}  

print '</table>';  


oci_close($conn);  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: A primary key column is what you need. Does `ATTENDEES` have an auto-incremented column or anything? Also, I certainly hope those are not the real credentials to your DB but if they are then you should definitely change them in your DB within the next few minutes.

Comment: By the way, this line is of extreme importance to you `<td align="center"><a  href="php_oracle_update2.php?CusID=<?=$objResult["CUSTOMERID"];?>">Edit</a></td>`

Comment: Fortunately for everyone, NO!! It is just for a college project to show server side functionality and updating an attendee record is one of the objectives. My table is really simple, has no primary key but I was thinking of just using the  email for this. In my form the name of it is attendee_email.

Comment: I highly recommend implementing a design using an auto-incremented field as the primary key because it will put you on the right track to DB normalization for both this project and future projects. If this was real then how would you handle a husband/wife couple that want to simply use the same email?...Anyways, if you insist on using the email as a primary key then specify it as such in your schema to make sure you never accidentally insert a duplicate. So then do `'href="modify_attendee2.php?email='.urlencode(row['attendee_email']).'"'`

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus, for the help and the advice going forward.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need an ID as primary key to work with. If you already have this column in your table then you can build your feature in two different ways: by URL or by FORM.

**URL**

you will need a url like

```
<a href="edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>">Edit</a>
```

then in your PHP file (edit_user.php) you will have to get the `user_id` value by `$_GET['user_id']`

**FORM**

you will need a form with a *hidden* input which its value will be the user id

```
<form action="edit_user.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

then in your PHP file (edit_user.php) you will have to get the `user_id` value by `$_POST['user_id']`

Comment: thanks for your time ponciste, the url way is working for me now!!